# In CRM 2011, which Class calls dll Plug-in installed?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to know which class of CRM 2011 calls the plug-in installed on.

I'm new to plug-ins but I think each call to them, uses the same process. 
I need to make them to work on a different instance .

Let me introduce an example. I have an implementation of `IPlugin` class with a member called `_log`.

```
public class Plugin : IPlugin { 
    private static String _log;
}
```

So, if I have asynchronous plug-in, each time plug triggers, I should have  new  object, right? When I watch the log file, I notice that in the same log there's more than one process of the plug-in. Example: "Log-> obj1.method_1, obj2.method_1" It's like there's only one instance for the class plug-in and each time the plug-in triggers, it just calls the `Execute()` method with a different *serviceProvider* parameter. It's that possible? Any idea?

Comment: I agree with @Daryl entirely here. You need to either accept an answer (if it satisfies you) or nag loudly telling us what's still wrong, unclear, confusing or plain unhelpful. That way you'll always succeed (or can conclude that your problem broke the collective competence of SO, which should be badgable somehow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've encountered a problem with your logic and have decided on a way to fix it that is not compatible with the way CRM is supposed to work. Take a step back and describe why you feel that "*each call must work on a different instance*".

As @Daryl correctly states, there isn't a way to change the caching of the `Plugin` object and that's precisely why the [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151102.aspx) states:

> For improved performance, Microsoft Dynamics CRM caches plug-in
>   instances. The plug-in's Execute method should be written to be
>   stateless because the constructor is not called for every invocation
>   of the plug-in. Also, multiple system threads could execute the
>   plug-in at the same time. All per invocation state information is
>   stored in the context, so you should not use global variables in
>   plug-ins or attempt to store any data in member variables for use
>   during the next plug-in invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'm guessing your having some multi-threading problems with plugins.  There is no way to change it so a new object gets created every time.  Any class level variables are going to create race conditions.  Why do you think that you need each plugin call to be in a different process?

### Edit 1

Why don't you just create a new object as the first step of your plugin, passing in the execution process?  Move all class level variables defined in your plugin to your new class.  That way you don't have to worry about multi-threading issues.

### Edit 2 - Example ##

```cs
// Your actual IPlugin class would only contain this, nothing else.
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {       
        new MyPluginLogic().ExecutePluginLogic(serviceProvider);    
    }
}

public class MyPluginLogic{
    private static String _log;

    public void ExecutePluginLogic(IServiceProvider serviceProvider){
        // Do what ever logic you were previously doing in your plugin class.
    }
}
```

If you setup your code this way, you are guaranteed to get a new `MyPluginLogic` object each time the plugin is called, which will eliminate any possible non-static race conditions.

If you're still having issues, post your code.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanx for your answer.  I modified my answer.  Could you please read that?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I don't understand  what you mean for "create a new object as the first step of your plugin"